# What is the correct way to concatenate and trim in TWIG

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm new to TWIG.  I can do this in PHP, but I'm looking for the right way to do it in the template using TWIG.

Controller code:

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getEntityManager();
        $properties = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Property')->findAll();

        return $this->render('MainBundle:Admin:index.html.twig', array(
            'bmproperty'     => $properties,
        ));
    }
```

TWIG Template:

```
{% for property in bmproperty %}
            <div {% if property.hasHoaLien == false %}class="nolien"{% else %}class="haslien"{% endif %}>
                <ul><li><a href="{{ path('MainBundle_Property_Edit', {'id' : property.id}) }}">
                            {% if property.houseNumber is null %} {{ property.street }}
                                Lot #{{ property.lotNumber }}
                            {% else %}
                                {{ property.houseNumber }} {{ property.street }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </a>
                    </li><li>
                    {% if property.user is not empty %}
                        {% for user in property.user %}
                            {{ user.fullname }},
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        {{ property.status }}
                    {% endif %}
                    </li><li>{{ property.type }}</li>{% if property.isOccupied == true %}<li>Occupied</li>{% else %}<li>Vacant</li>{% endif %}{% if property.inArrears == true %}<li>Yes</li>{% else %}<li>No</li>{% endif %}</ul>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

My problem is with this snippet in the above code:

```
{% for user in property.user %}
  {{ user.fullname }},
{% endfor %}
```

There are two user names on this line and I'm simply trying to separate them with a comma and then trim the last comma.

Do I assign the two users to a variable in the template then just use the TRIM option in TWIG?  If so, I'm not sure how to concatenate them to a single variable in TWIG template.

Comment: `{{ proper.user|join(',') }}` ?

Comment: {{ property.user|join(',') }} actually works, but I can't access the user's other attributes, like: {{ property.user.fullname|join(',') }} which throws an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use join with a non array variable. In the example you use:

```
{{ property.user.fullname|join(',') }}
```

Join works as a php implode function, so the argument must be an array.
fullname is not a member of property.user, but a member of each of the property.user.0.fullname, property.user.1.fullname

To cancatenate 2 or more string you can use the ~ operator

```
{{ property.user.0.fullname ~', ' ~ property.user.1.fullname }}
```

My approach would be to add a variable that holds the names, and then implode it after the for

```
{% set arr ={} %
{% for key,user in property.user %}
  {% set arr = arr|merge({key: user.fullname}) %}  
{% endfor %}
{{ arr|join(',') }}
```

Comment: Beautifully answered.  Thank you.

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon.  It's only returning the first or last user in the array... doesn't look like it's concatenating them.

Comment: Any idea what's going on?

Comment: first of all sorry for the long silence, i check the issue and apparently the merge doesn't work well with numeric index, so we need to change them to strings first
`{% set arr = arr|merge({(key~'_'): user.fullname}) %}  `

let me know if it works

Comment: That did it.  Thank you for not giving up on the question... your explanation is a teaching moment.  Great job.